# Vb.net image upload/storing

Tags: vb.net, authentication, ftp

Hello before anyone replies with 'search it's there' well I have searched and i have googled so here goes:

Is there any easier way to uploading images to a website other than using FTP? I was thinking maybe use MySQL (connect to my webhost MySQL?) but not sure also I have a site with an upload script and you can login etc

Really it'd be great if I could let's say login to an account from vb and then upload image via that account

I've tried several things but not quiete successful, any recommendations or links i could try??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure, but since you said you had an upload script, just an idea. Couldn't you just (Assuming the upload script is in PHP), Request the Filename as a $_REQUEST, and pass that to a input of type file. Then access the PHP Script by using a webrequest? I'm not sure if this would work, but it's just an idea. 
Hope this idea helps you :)

Comment: Yeah it's in php and I kind of get what you mean, I've been meaning to look at the webrequest so maybe it's worth doing, as I say I'm wanting to find out the best way of doing :)